# Meaning of " you came when you did"

Tags: meaning

What does the sentence " you came when you did" mean ?especially the term " when you did".The meaning is not apparent.

Comment: What specifically are you confused about?

Comment: What is the full sentence?

Comment: @BillJ Is the *when you did*  a fused relative? (in its most likely reading?)

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Yes, especially in something like "I'm glad you came [when you did]".

Comment: Please edit this question to include the full sentence not just a fragment, and if possible the broader context.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually used in the context of *I am glad* you came when you did. It needs something in front of it. It makes little sense outside of that. It means what it appears to mean; I am glad that you arrived when you arrived. You're arrival was fortuitous. You got here just in time.

It could also be used in the negative; *Too bad* you came when you did. Meaning you got here just in time for trouble or danger. Without something in front of it this would be tautological. *You came when you did*. Indeed. You are here now that you are here.